# Access querystring parameter values in xsl

Tags: xslt, query-string

I have a contact us page created by xsl. the submit button in that page redirects to a thank you page also created by xsl. Now I want to get the output as `Thank You <name i enter>`. The  is passed in the url as a querystring. Now how can i access it in the page? Is there any equivalent like `request.getParameter(<parameter name>)` in xsl that i can use here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using code to generate the page via XSLT, or are you simply serving up an XML file with an `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` processing instruction?  If it's the former, perhaps there is a way to get the value in advance and pass it into the XSLT as a parameter.  Could you show us some of the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

**Use the [`QueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) property of the [`HttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx) class**.

Here is an example (C#) how this property can be used:

int loop1, loop2;

```
// Load NameValueCollection object.
NameValueCollection coll=Request.QueryString; 
// Get names of all keys into a string array.
String[] arr1 = coll.AllKeys; 
for (loop1 = 0; loop1 < arr1.Length; loop1++) 
{
   Response.Write("Key: " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr1[loop1]) + "<br>");
   String[] arr2 = coll.GetValues(arr1[loop1]);
   for (loop2 = 0; loop2 < arr2.Length; loop2++) 
   {
      Response.Write("Value " + loop2 + ": " + Server.HtmlEncode(arr2[loop2]) + "<br>");
   }
}
```

**In your case, when you find the wanted name-value pair, get the value and pass it as a parameter to the XSLT transformation**. In .NET one way to do this is to use the [`XsltArgumentList.AddParam()`](http://XsltArgumentList.AddParam)  method

**Again, here is a complete C# example**:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Xsl;

public class Sample
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        // Create the XslCompiledTransform and load the stylesheet.
        XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslt.Load("order.xsl");

        // Create the XsltArgumentList.
        XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();

        // Create a parameter which represents the current date and time.
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        xslArg.AddParam("date", "", d.ToString());

        // Transform the file. 
        using (XmlWriter w = XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"))
        {
            xslt.Transform("order.xml", xslArg, w);
        }
    }
}
```

**The XSLT transformation must have a global `xsl:param` named `date`:**

```
<xsl:param name="date"/>
```

And the above code sets this global parameter to the wanted value. Then in the XSLT code, simply access the parameter as `$date`.